# Can $\mathbb{C}$ be extended to a larger topological field that is also algebraically closed and complete?

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field, topological-rings

We know that $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraically closed topological field of characteristic zero with respect to the Euclidean topology, which is induced by the (complete) absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$. If one were to adjoin an extra point, say $\alpha$, to $\mathbb{C}$, then clearly $\overline{\mathbb{C}(\alpha)}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(\alpha)$, is an algebraically closed transcendental extension of $\mathbb{C}$.

Is it possible to extend the Euclidean topology to $\overline{\mathbb{C}(\alpha)}$ in such a way that addition, multiplication and inversion are continuous? (so that the extension is also a topological field). If so, is this topology induced by some norm?

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no larger *algebrically closed* field containing $\mathbb C$, since this is already algebrically closed

Comment: @Alessandro That is not correct. The field $\mathbb{C}(\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$ is the field of rational functions in the "indeterminate" $\alpha$. Its algebraic closure is larger, the field of [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series#Algebraic_closedness_of_Puiseux_series).

Comment: @plop, you're absolutely right. My bad, I confused "algebrically closed" with "algebraic closure" for some reason